# Passing angular app URL with query parameters with other users

Tags: angular, routes, query-string

I have requirement where I want to transfer filters state of page with other user. For example, When I am on particular page and applying same filters.I want to share URL with some state i.e applied filters with other users.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you want to achieve and share what you've tried.

Comment: @Athanasios Kataras  I want  to share angular app URL with other user but I want to keep state of data filter I had applied on that page. I am trying to pass query param in URL so that I can retrieve that data and apply filter on shared URL.

Comment: Ok, I understood now. Check my response below.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters

Set it up in your routing

```
{ path: 'hero/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent }
```

Consume in your component

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.hero$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
      this.service.getHero(params.get('id')))
  );
}
```

Or the no observable alternative

```
ngOnInit() {
  let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

  this.hero$ = this.service.getHero(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution:

We can add our custom key value in queryParams. If it is object you can stringify it.

```
const tree = this.router.createUrlTree([], { queryParams: {productImpacted:this.productImpacted, Division: this.businessUnit, Region: JSON.stringify(this.regionFilter),OU:this.operatingUnit} });
  console.log(this.serializer.serialize(tree)); // "/?foo=a&bar=42"
  let url = window.location.origin+this.serializer.serialize(tree);
```

You can retrieve data from query param using below code

```
 this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {

    var data = params[key]
```

});

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this

`curenturl = window.location.href
paramobj = JSON.parse('{"' + currenturl.split('?')[1].replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g, '":"') + '"}', function (k, v) { return k === '' ? v : decodeURIComponent(v) })`

You will get object of properties in url

Comment: While a solution, this is not the angular way and could lead to very bad code.